# MySQL trigger 'Can't update table'

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm trying to make a trigger in order to insert a new row a table once you insert a new record.

It looks like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS insertOcupacioLlorer$$
CREATE TRIGGER insertOcupacioLlorer BEFORE INSERT ON OCUPACIO
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.OCU_codiCasa = 'A0325IGM05' THEN
INSERT INTO OCUPACIO(OCU_codiCasa,OCU_dataInici,OCU_dataFi,OCU_tipus,OCU_idReserva,OCU_dataBloqueig)
VALUES
('A0323IGM05',NEW.OCU_dataInici,NEW.OCU_dataFi,NEW.OCU_tipus,NEW.OCU_idReserva,NEW.OCU_dataBloqueig);
END IF;
IF NEW.OCU_codiCasa = 'A0323IGM05' THEN
INSERT INTO OCUPACIO(OCU_codiCasa,OCU_dataInici,OCU_dataFi,OCU_tipus,OCU_idReserva,OCU_dataBloqueig)
VALUES
('A0325IGM05',NEW.OCU_dataInici,NEW.OCU_dataFi,NEW.OCU_tipus,NEW.OCU_idReserva,NEW.OCU_dataBloqueig);
END IF;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I insert a new record I get

```
#1442 - Can't update table 'OCUPACIO' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger
```

Well I guess the trigger maybe calling itself again once is executed and this produces the error.

If I can't achieve what I want with a trigger, is there another way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes you cant do insert/update on the same table via the trigger on which trigger gets executed before - after event. Could you explain a bit what you are actually trying to do ?

Comment: I just want to duplicate a record with a new `OCU_codiCasa` when I insert a new row

Comment: no its not possible using trigger you can not do insert/update on the same table.

Comment: So the best way is to do it in the API layer instead of on the DB one?

Comment: can you explain exactly what you want to do with that table on insert

Comment: Thats right how ever if you want to add the data to a different table then trigger would be best instead of writing the code in the application level. Meaning you insert something on table1 and want the duplicate in table2 or you delete something from table1 and keep the deleted data in table2 and so on.